# When Reloading Maven in IntelliJ, I receive the following message: 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:jar:2.3.5' was not found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, soap

The following code runs when started.

```
package org.example;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

@WebService
public class SimpleSOAPServer {

    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name + "!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/soap";
        Endpoint.publish(url, new SimpleSOAPServer());
        System.out.println("Server is running at: " + url);
    }
}
```

However, during the build, the following error message is thrown under the 'sync' tab in IntelliJ.

```
com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:jar:2.3.5 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of maven-central has elapsed or updates are forced

Try to run Maven import with -U flag (force update snapshots)
```

I tried with different versions of the Maven dependency, but it didn't help; instead, other error messages occurred, and the code didn't start. I also added the 'repositories' section in the pom.xml because it was missing when creating the project, but it didn't change anything either. The dependency is, however, available in the Maven Central Repo.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SimpleSOAPServer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
<!--        Dependency for: "javax.jws.WebMethod;"-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: First why have you defined central repository manually in your pom file? Which Maven version do you use? which JDK ? Log file?

Comment: Can you try deleting `com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-ri` in your local repository?

Comment: Use the `-U` flag to override this message.

Comment: For khmarbaise: The reason I included the central repository is probably because I have little experience with it :) *** Maven version: Bundled (Maven 3)  Version: 3.9.5 *** OpenJDK 17.0.2. *** In Log file: com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:jar:2.3.5 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of maven-central has elapsed or updates are forced

Try to run Maven import with -U flag (force update snapshots)

Comment: For dan1st: what do I have to delete exactly? the entire path or only the last one folder (jaxws-ri)?

Comment: For Thorbjorn: I already used the cleaning and installing with '-U' but it has'nt helped any further

Comment: It seems like it failed to get the artifact at some point and cached the "failed" status. Navigate to the artifact's folder in your Maven Local and remove the .lastUpdated file from it